# AchartEngine: Adjusting Y axis and increasing Legend size?

Tags: android, achartengine

How can I adjust my `AchartEngine` graph to do the following:

1. Move `Y-axis` title back so that it is not intruding on graph area (padding?)
2. Increase the size of the `legend` and move it down vertically further away from the graph?

**Image of Current Graph:**

[image]

**Code relating to graph:**

```
public class LineGraph4 {

    //declaring instance of context
    protected Context context;

    public Intent getIntent(Context context){

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);



        /**
         * Series 1
         */
        //trying to pull Scores data from SQLite database for graphs 
        List<Integer> l= db.getAllGameScores();

        //creating y axis array of values by converting list to array.
        int[] y=convertIntegers(l);

        //creating x axis array of values dynamically
        int totalGames= db.getTotalGamesPlayed();
        int[] x = new int[totalGames];

        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){

            x[i]=i;


        }
        //creating and naming the line
        TimeSeries series= new TimeSeries("Score");

        //adding both the x and y values to the series
        for(int i=0; i <x.length; i++){

            series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }


        /**
         * Series 2
         */
        //trying to pull Scores data from SQLite database for graphs 
        List<Integer> l2= db.getAllAverageMeditationLevels();

        //creating y axis array of values by converting list to array.
        int[] y2=convertIntegers(l2);

        //creating x axis array of values dynamically
        int totalGames2= db.getTotalGamesPlayed();
        int[] x2 = new int[totalGames2];

        for(int i=0; i<x2.length; i++){

            x2[i]=i;


        }
        //creating and naming the line
        TimeSeries series2= new TimeSeries("Avg meditation");

        //adding both the x and y values to the series
        for(int i=0; i <x2.length; i++){

            series2.add(x2[i], y2[i]);
        }


        /**
         * Series 3
         */
        //trying to pull Scores data from SQLite database for graphs 
        List<Integer> l3= db.getAllAverageAttentionLevels();

        //creating y axis array of values by converting list to array.
        int[] y3=convertIntegers(l3);

        //creating x axis array of values dynamically
        int totalGames3= db.getTotalGamesPlayed();
        int[] x3 = new int[totalGames3];

        for(int i=0; i<x3.length; i++){

            x3[i]=i;


        }
        //creating and naming the line
        TimeSeries series3= new TimeSeries("Avg Attention");

        //adding both the x and y values to the series
        for(int i=0; i <x3.length; i++){

            series3.add(x3[i], y3[i]);
        }




        //declaring the Multiple series dataset that the single data sets are added to
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset= new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        //adding multiple series 
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);
        dataset.addSeries(series3);


        //renderer that changes the look etc of the first line (score)
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer= new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);//set line colour
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        //renderer that changes the look etc of the second line (score)
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer2= new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer2.setColor(Color.WHITE);//set line colour
        renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

        // renderer that changes the look etc of the second line (score)
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer3.setColor(Color.RED);// set line colour
        renderer3.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer3.setFillPoints(true);


        //Only related to the display of the graphs x and y values
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float val = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18, metrics);


        //renderer that changes the look etc of the overall graph
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multRenderer= new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        //adding single to multiple
        multRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        multRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
        multRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);
        multRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        multRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        multRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(val);
        multRenderer.setChartTitle("");
        multRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(40);
        multRenderer.setXTitle("Games");
        multRenderer.setYTitle("Value");
        multRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25); //sets size of numbers of axis
        //setting size of text for labels, legend etc
        multRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(22); 
        multRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        multRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(val);

        //creating the intent
        Intent intent= ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, multRenderer, "Summary Graph");

        return intent;

    }

    /**
     * Mehthod that converts a list
     * of integers to an array of lists
     * @param integers
     * @return
     */
    public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can use `renderer.setMargins(new int[] {top, left, bottom, right})`. In your case you will have to increase the left margin.

For the second question, use `renderer.setLegendHeight(heightInPixels)`